# How to specify a date range in Dark Sky API

Tags: python, darksky

I am new to using APIs so I apologize if this is not a helpful question. I cannot find in the documentation of how to specify a range of dates to pull weather data from.
Do you know how to do this?

`request=request.get = ('[darksky api URL/key], [LAT], [LON], [952128000], [954720000]')`

The two numbers at the end of the above request are two dates one month apart 3/3/2000 to 4/3/2000.
It works if I include one date in the API call but not both. Is that not possible with this API?
Dark Sky has a limit of 1000 API calls. How would I make that many without calling each individually?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Dark Sky Api Docs it only accepts only one timestamp for a forecast 
[Reference to the section in the docs](https://darksky.net/dev/docs#time-machine-request-parameters)

Based on the docs Dark Sky does not offer any method in the API to request a range of dates for the weather.

The only solution using Dark Sky would be to use multiple API calls.